# Is it an undefined behavior when use the pointer that return from operator new as a pointer to element of array

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
int main(){
  auto* ptr = (int*) ::operator new(sizeof(int)*10, std::align_val_t(alignof(int)));  //#1
  ptr[1] = 4; //#a
}
```

Consider the above code, what the standard says are listed in the following:

[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation)

> 1. The pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer to any suitable complete object type ([new.delete.single]) and then used to access the object or array in the storage allocated

[expr.new#8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#8)

> 2. If the allocated type is a non-array type, the allocation function's name is operator new and the deallocation function's name is operator delete. If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation function's name is operator new[] and the deallocation function's name is operator delete[].

[expr.new#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#1)

> 3. If the entity is a non-array object, the new-expression returns a pointer to the object created. If it is an array, the new-expression returns a pointer to the initial element of the array

And the rules about pointer arithmatic says:
[expr.add#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#4)

> 4. If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n elements,86 the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[i+j] if 0≤ i+j ≤ n; otherwise, the **behavior is undefined**.

So, I wonder Is it an undefined behavior when use the pointer at #a? I think it violate the bullet 4. In addition, at the look of implementation of std::allocate of `MSVC`. It seems to use operator new() to allocate the space and use the return pointer as a pointer to element of array.

It seems to the standard does not say what the return pointer point to what original object when directly invoke ::operator new(...). It only says the return pointer that resulted from invoking such allocate function can be converted to a pointer to an object which has suitably aligned.

#### UPDATE:

what I concerned is [dynamic-construction-of-arrays](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html#dynamic-construction-of-arrays)

The most implementation of std::vector use the std::allocate and std::vector has a non-static data member record the result from std::allocate. When use the object of std::vector as `arr[i]`, the implementation will use the non-static data member as the pointer to element of array type to access `arr[i]`. I think it should be UB? I.E, we are permitted to use the pointer that return from allocation function as the operand of `new-placement` to construct an object, However If we use the pointer to access `ith` object or any iterator to access `ith` object, It means it's UB?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216945/discussion-on-question-by-jack-x-is-it-an-undefined-behavior-when-use-the-pointe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression:

```
::operator new(sizeof(int)*10, std::align_val_t(alignof(int)));
```

is a function call expression to the global allocation function. It is not using the `new` expression to allocate storage and construct an object or array of objects. The global allocator functions only return raw storage and do not construct objects in the memory allocated.

Inside [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation)

> 1. The pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer to any suitable complete object type ([new.delete.single]) and then used to access **the object** or array in the storage allocated [...]

**the object** is an object that is not implicitly created. It is supposed to be created according to [[intro.object]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#1) in the code.

So, in this condition, you know that the expression `ptr[1]` has conceptualy 2 undefined behavior:

- `ptr+1` is undefined behavior because `ptr` [value](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-3.sentence-8) is not a pointer to array [expr.add](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.3)
- `*(ptr+1)` is undefined behavior because the value of `ptr` is not *pointer to object* [[expr.unary.op]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.unary#op-1)

---

According to c++20 this code has a well defined behavior. Because an implicitly created array object of type `int[N]` with `N>1` with its elements also implicitly created would give this code defined behavior.

[[intro.object]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#13.sentence-3)

> Any implicit or explicit invocation of a function named operator new or operator new[] implicitly creates objects in the returned region of storage and returns a pointer to a suitable created object.

[[intro.object]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#10)

> Some operations are described as implicitly creating objects within a specified region of storage. For each operation that is specified as implicitly creating objects, that operation implicitly creates and starts the lifetime of zero or more objects of implicit-lifetime types ([basic.types]) in its specified region of storage if doing so would result in the program having defined behavior. If no such set of objects would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined. If multiple such sets of objects would give the program defined behavior, it is unspecified which such set of objects is created.

These two paragraphes are a kind of revolution in the way the language is specified:

- What happen is not determined, rather it is a possible set *implicitly creates and starts the lifetime of zero or more objects of implicit-lifetime types*
- the constraint does not depend on a given point in the code or in the program execution, rather it depends on the entire program execution: *if doing so would result in the program having defined behavior*.

So code validity depends on an induction, this is what I think is a revolution. For example in the case abose, the reasoning would be: *let's suppose that the allocation function call would have returned a pointer to an object of type `int [1]`, so the code as defined behavior, so the assumption is correct*

But this implicit object remain hypothetical until the entire program has executed. For exemple if somewhere else in the code an `int` is created at `ptr[2]` the reasoning could be changed to:*let's suppose that the allocation function call would have returned a pointer to an object of type `int [2]`, so the code as defined behavior, so the assumption is correct*

Comment: After a bit of reading, what I understand from your first paragraphs is "`::operator new(sizeof(int)*10, std::align_val_t(alignof(int)));` is a function call to the global allocator which just allocates raw memory. It is not an expression using the `new` operator which first uses the global allocator and then constructs an object of the class specified. So the pointer returned is a pointer to raw memory only, similar to what you would get with `malloc()` and not a constructed object.". Is that a correct reading?

Comment: @Oliv  I'm pretty sure the code is absolutely UB under c++17, you interpret this very well. However I have some confusion about what c++20 says. 1. How to determine whether **invocation of a function named operator new ** will product an object or an array? It's obviously that invocation of `operator new[]` will product an array.

Comment: @RichardChambers It seems to the c++17 standard or earlier indeed not specified what an object to which the return pointer of invocation of  `operator new` or `malloc()` point.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, you can correct my answer if the english can be improved for clarity. English is not my native language.

Comment: @jackX I will try to develop the comment on the other question in the answer. Thinking about it, the way they specified it is a kind of revolution: code validity is induced not deduced!

Comment: @jackX thinking about this and reading this answer, while the code is UB because you are using an array of `int`, I would expect this to work anyway. However with an actual class it would not unless you added an additional step of object construction within the array. However at that point you are having to manage your own memory and object lifetimes because `delete` would not know it was an array and would not perform the necessary object destruction of the array elements. So this is really just using `malloc()`.

Comment: @Oliv I try to summarize what c++20 says, I'm not sure my reading is right. It says. what an object to which the return pointer of invocation  of a allocate function can be specified by the **cast**, If such conversion result can make program have well defined. Thereof , what type can be specified is these objects that have implicit lifetime type. Right? For example, If defined a class type that has virtual function , then the result would be UB if dereference the pointer.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, I agree that in this question , the invocation of `operator new` is equivalent to invocation of `malloc`.

Comment: @Oliv  That means , for the example `auto ptr = operator new(sizeof(char)*16, std::align_val_t(alignof(int)))`. We can consider the pointer `ptr` as a pointer to array of 4 int, that means we can obtain a pointer to the element of this array by `auto elementPtr = &*ptr`, and  `elementPtr ` can be used as the operand of Additive operators. The same, we can also consider the `ptr` as an object of int. They can all result in the program having defined behavior, Right?

Comment: @jackX This is what I have understood, yes.

Comment: @Oliv This is a way that give the responsibility to programers, that means we can interpret the address return from such allocate function as pointer to any object that has implicit lifetime.